# Oracle Procedure: Read from Table A and if not found go to Table B

Tags: oracle, jdbc, stored-functions

I want to read data from either from Table-A or Table-B. My database is oracle and procedure must use minimum number of queries. Requirement is to read from one table and if data is not available go to other table. I wrote following procedure,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE READ(myId IN VARCHAR2, aout OUT   SYS_REFCURSOR,  bout OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
  IS
  temp_acout_type A_TABLE%ROWTYPE;
  BEGIN
     OPEN aout FOR SELECT * FROM A_TABLE WHERE ID = myId;
     FETCH aout into temp_acout_type ;
     if aout%NOTFOUND then
        OPEN bout FOR SELECT * FROM B_TABLE WHERE ID = myId;
     end if;
 END;
```

I'm calling this function from java side. My problem is once I fetch the cursor in the procedure, cursor will lost the data. I observed this from Java client since `ResultSet`in java side is empty ( Queries in procedure will only have 1 record since it's searching from primary key) , although it must contain data.

I need a way to implement above logic but without using more queries ( ex: first check data is available at Table-A ). Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always open both cursors in the PL/SQL stored proc, and then in Java, fetch data from the first one, and then only fetch from the second one if you didn't get data from the first one. That would prevent unnecessary reads from taking place (opening a cursor doesn't do any reads; it sets up the execution path ready for when you're wanting to fetch the data).

Alternatively, you could do a union all between the two tables and only select the first row (where first means from the first query there's data in).

Answer (score 1):

Check the count of rows in the table. You could use **row-limiting** clause like `ROWNUM` or `FETCH` in 12c.

Since you are saying that ID is the primary key thus it would fetch only 1 row, then simply do it like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO var_cnt FROM A_TABLE WHERE ID = myId;

IF var_cnt > 0
THEN 
   OPEN aout FOR SELECT * FROM A_TABLE WHERE ID = myId;
ELSE
   OPEN bout FOR SELECT * FROM B_TABLE WHERE ID = myId;
END IF;
```

However, you cannot be sure if the row being fetched will definitely be there in the cursor result set, since meanwhile some other session might **DELETE** The row prior to the **OPEN FOR** statement is being executed.

For sanity, I would suggest, use **Analytic COUNT() OVER()** in the **explicit cursor** query.

Comment: Is there a possibility to use only two main select queries omitting `select count(*)` somehow ?

Comment: Yes, using `count() over()`. Then you would count the rows in the same query.